# ejabberd-16.09 clustering and namenode issue

Tags: ejabberd

I am working as root and using centos7.
I have installed ejabberd 16.09 in two different machines using RPM package. In both the cases I have the same nodename (**ejabberd@localhost**) and same host (**ejabberd.c.southern-silo-174209.internal**) since I cloned the disk of the first machine into the second. Everything is working fine.

Trouble arises when I want to cluster these machines. Since the disks are clones I have the exact copies of **.erlang.cookie** and **ejabberd.yml** in both the machines (I verified the contents personally). Now when I execute this command, on either of the machines, **ejabberdctl join_cluster "ejabberd@localhost"** I get an error saying : **{not_master,ejabberd@localhost}**. This seemed natural as how can the cluster be formed when I am having two same nodenames.

To overcome this problem I freshly installed ejabberd in my second machine. But to my surprise it again gives me the **same nodename!!**(ejabberd@localhost) So to achieve clustering, the natural thing would be to change the nodenames. Ok lets try it!!

Following these steps
[ejabberd change nodename guide](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/managing/#change-computer-hostname)

I was able to follow till step 3.

[OLDNODE=ejabberd@localhost and NEWNODE=ejabberd@myfirstmachine where myfirstmachine is the hostname of my computer]

For step 4, I coudnt find any **/var/lib/ejabberd** directory in my system(probably because I didnt create user ejabberd). Instead I found this directory called "ejabberd@localhost" inside **/opt/ejabberd-16.09/database** which contained all the .DAT, .DCD and .DCL files. So I created a folder **/opt/ejabberd-16.09/database/oldfiles** and migrated all the files from ejabberd@localhost directory to this directory.

Following on everything went fine till step 6. When I execute step 7 I get the following error.

**Can't install fallback from "/tmp/new.backup" at node ejabberd@localhost: {"Cannot install fallback",
                                                                           {"No disc resident schema on local node",
                                                                            [ejabberd@myfirstmachine]}}**

So here I am stuck. I just want to attain clustering of different machines. I have no interest in namenode. I even tried another technique and that was to add ERLANG_NODE in ejabberdctl.cfg but after adding I am unable to access the web admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want any older data from any of node then you can follow below steps for clustering.

1. Stop All nodes
2. Remove everything from opt/ejabberd-16.09/database directory in all three nodes using rm-rf opt/ejabberd-16.09/database
3. Change ERLANG_NODE in all three node as per 'ejabberd@hostname' where hostname should be routable
4. Restart all node
5. Now join cluster from node 1 to node 2 using ejabberdctl join_cluster 'ejabberd@node2'
6. After that go to node 3 and use same command as above ejabberdctl join_cluster 'ejabberd@node2'
7. Your cluster should be setup now.It can be checked by ejabberdctl list_cluster

Comment: In step 3 what do you mean by routable? Cant I use the hostname of my machine which is the output of the command "hostname" in Centos 7?

Comment: If I do use the hostname of the machine in ERLANG_NODE, then after restarting I am unable to access the web admin even though the status shows it is running in that node.

Comment: Routable means your dns should have entry for that hostname.In short, all three nodes should ping each other with hostname which is used in ERLANG_NODE.

Comment: tried that but not working. It says nodedown even though the status shows running. After adding ERLANG_NODE in cfg file on either of the machines I am unable to access the web admin interface, maybe that is the reason why clustering is not working. Why is the webpage not coming after changing the namenode even though the status shows running.

Comment: [myfirstmachine_logs](https://storage.googleapis.com/atrazan/first.txt)  [mysecondmachine_logs](https://storage.googleapis.com/atrazan/second.txt)

Comment: Your web page is not working because your admin user is not registered in node.Since you have cleared database folder, you have to register admin user agina.After that you will be able to access admin page.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution worked. I really had no clue that I would need to register the admin again. I did it and now my cluster is setup. One more point I would like to mention is that I am not having identical ejabberd.yml files in both machines but still I managed to create a cluster. How is that possible? And if I need identical copies of the .yml file, which one should I copy since they have different hostnames and admin accounts

Comment: admin account should be same.Node name must be different even though they are in cluster.